# How to create dynamic multilingual web application using Asp.net 3.5 and c# 3.0

Tags: c#, asp.net, multilingual

I have a web application in english language. My client wants it in Arabic. I have a lot of work with database. When I searched multilingual solution I found that we have created a resource file where we define key/value of all text. But want a way that all my database that automatically converted into Arabic and vice versa. Is there any way to do this.

Answer (score 1):

I highly recommend against using automated translation for a website. Either use a real translation service with humans or just use the Google translate widget.
Google downranks automatically translated websites because of low quality and index spamming.

Answer (score 0):

Clearly there is no built-in way to translate any arbitrary text from one language to another. I would suggest using an API like [Google Translate](https://developers.google.com/translate/v2/getting_started) (bear in mind that this is a paid service).

Perhaps you could use this to define and implement an `ITranslationService`, which you then inject into your data access services, allowing you to automatically attempt to translate any data returned to your from your database, based on the current Culture.